# comment form doesn't load when using django-comments-xtd

Tags: python, html, django, django-comments

I am new to both Django and Python and am trying to create my blog.My setup consists of Django 2.0.7 and Python 3.6.5 running on windows 10.I have configured only one app named "personal".In my case the the page loads with "0 Comments Posted" and it doesn't renders the comment form.

Below is  my code snippet

*settings.py* config

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'personal',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django_comments_xtd',
    'django_comments',
]

COMMENTS_APP = "django_comments_xtd"
COMMENTS_XTD_CONFIRM_EMAIL = True 
COMMENTS_XTD_SALT = b"es-war-einmal-una-bella-princesa-in-a-beautiful-castle"
COMMENTS_XTD_FROM_EMAIL = 'noreply@example.com'
COMMENTS_XTD_CONTACT_EMAIL = 'helpdesk@example.com'
COMMENTS_XTD_MAX_THREAD_LEVEL = 0 
COMMENTS_XTD_THREADED_EMAILS = False

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'noreply@example.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'abcd1234'
```

*urls.py* (urls.py under personal app)

```
urlpatterns = [
  ........................
  ........................
    url(r'^comments/', include('django_comments_xtd.urls')),

    ]

models.py (under personal app)

from django.db import models

class mycomments(models.Model):

   mail = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
   phonenumber = models.IntegerField()

   class Meta:
      db_table = "mycomments"
```

*views* (under personal app)

```
def page1(request):
    mycomm =Recipiecomments()
    return render(request, 'personal/blackforestcake.html',locals())
```

And Finally *page_detail.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>My Page</title>


{% load static %}   

    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="fh5co-loader"></div>

    <div id="page">
    {% include 'personal/head.html' %}
    {% load comments %}
    {% load comments_xtd %}


    <div id="fh5co-author">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row top-line animate-box">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h2>My Blog detail</h2>     
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <p class="animate-box"><img src="{% static "personal/img/pic" %}" class="img-responsive" alt="image"></p>
                    <div class="testimony animate-box">
                        <blockquote>
                        <h3>Topic 1:</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Detail 1</li>
                                               </ul>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>

{% get_comment_count for mycomm as comment_count %}
 &nbsp;&sdot;&nbsp;
 {{ comment_count }} comments have been posted.
</div>

{% if mycomm.allow_comments %}
<div class="comment">
  <h4 class="text-center">Your comment</h4>
  <div class="well">
    {% render_comment_form for mycomm %}
  </div>
</div>
{% endif %}

{% if comment_count %}
<hr/>
<ul class="media-list">
  {% render_xtdcomment_tree for mycomm %}
</ul>
{% endif %}

    </div>

    <div class="gototop js-top">
        <a href="#" class="js-gotop"><i class="icon-arrow-up"></i></a>
    </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have used the following tutorial for the same.http://django-comments-xtd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html.Also all my html pages are static and have been hosted on "personal/templates/personal" location

Answer (score 0):

remove the if tag surrounding the comment form tag i.e

```
{% if mycomm.allow_comments %}
<div class="comment">
  <h4 class="text-center">Your comment</h4>
  <div class="well">
    {% render_comment_form for mycomm %}
  </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

should now be

```
<div class="comment">
  <h4 class="text-center">Your comment</h4>
  <div class="well">
    {% render_comment_form for mycomm %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Now the form started displaying however it is displaying on the top of the page and is non editable.

Comment: I don't know why it isn't editable but i think you should use the {% get_comment_form %} tag and iterate over it and see if it works